# Selenium 3.12 / Java 10.0.1 throws SocketException randomly - Permission denied: connect

Tags: java, selenium

About each 2nd hour I get the following error shown in Eclipse:

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect

After a reboot of my PC everything is fine again - no more problems for about 2 hours ...

My PC:

Win 7 / 64 Bit - all updates installed
FireFox 60.0.1 / 64 Bit
Java 10.0.1
Selenium 3.12
Geckodriver 0.20.1 / 64 Bit
Eclipse 4.7.3a

Does someone know a solution please?

Can I fix this problem without rebooting my PC e.g. by resetting "TCP/IP" ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

Update:

Ohhh, I'm NOT doing a driver.quit() at the end during development because I want to see the browser content ...; may be that's the problem? ...

Anyway: Is there a way to fix it without rebooting the PC ?

Comment: I would imagine the missing driver.quit() is causing the problem. Do you have loads of instances of chromedriver.exe (or whatever driver you're using) open when you get this error? You can just manually close them.

Comment: you could also write a .bat file and add TASKKILL /F /IM chromedriver.exe